# Custom view in UITableView header overlapping UIViewController view

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` that has a `UIView` (SelectorDropDown)that, when the user clicks on it, expands another `UIView` (Belongs to SelectorDropDown). The idea can be thought as custom dropdown view and it looks like that:

[image]

The way I add the expandable view in my layout is by adding it in my `UIViewController` view despite belonging to the SelectorDropDown view inside my `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. If I don't do it like that, the expandable view gets hidden. The function that handles the addition:

```
func setUpDropDown(with viewController:UIViewController){

    holderViewController = viewController

    //Adding drop drown view
    holderViewController!.view.addSubview(dropDrownView)
    holderViewController!.view.bringSubviewToFront(dropDrownView)

    dropDrownView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dropDrownView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    dropDrownView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    dropDrownView.backgroundColor = .red
    //dropDrownViewHeightConstraint = dropDrownView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderViewController!.view.bottomAnchor)
    dropDrownViewHeightConstraint = dropDrownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([dropDrownViewHeightConstraint])

}
```

However, ask expected, when I hide the `UITableView`, the expandable view stays because, in fact, belongs to the `UIViewController` view.

[image]

Is there a way I can sort it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a refrence to it inside the vc and when you hide the table do

```
dropDrownView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: That you for you reply. I thought about that but I was trying to find another approach if it is possible. If not I will accept your answer